# On what bases the Java finds the maximum and minimum values of String array?

Tags: java, arrays, max, min

Today I was practising java programing and come across a program making me wonder that what will happen if I find maximum and minimum of a String in an Array.

```
    // Creating an Array List
    ArrayList<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Adding values
    myArrayList.add("Hello World");
    myArrayList.add("My Name is Some Body");
    myArrayList.add("I am many Years old");
    myArrayList.add("And I love Java programming");

    // To find min and max in Array
    String min = Collections.min(myArrayList);
    String max = Collections.max(myArrayList);

    // Print min and max in Array
    System.out.println("Min: " +min);
    System.out.println("Max: " +max);
```

It gives an output of:

```
Min: And I love Java programming
Max: My Name is Some Body
```

I was curious that on what bases it determines the maximum and minimum of a String array? And how can it be useful in a program?

Comment: Do you want to count number of characters or words in a string?

Comment: It's alphabetical. Letters have a numerical value assigned to them in the ASCII table, and a is smaller than b and so on

Comment: The first part is answered easily by the Javadoc: "Returns the minimum element of the given collection, according to the natural ordering of its elements." For the second part ... I guess, you would be searching for opportunities to do something useful with "the natural order" of strings.

Comment: First character of the element A < H < I < M

Comment: The order is called lexicographic.

Comment: As dasblinkenlight said ,The strings are compared in lexicographic order.The comparator makes use of the compareTo method of the object (in this case String)  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_compareto.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot Kick, dasblinkenlight, and especially @EddyG and everyone for your very informative and helpful answers! Your efforts and helps will never be forgotten by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Collections.max` and `Collections.min` compare objects in their natural order.

For `String`s, it's lexicographic (i.e. alphabetic) comparison.

Amongst the many uses of natural order comparison is the fact you can easily sort `String` alphabetically.

Answer (score 1):

It's doing String comparison in this case. Check the min method in collections class.

```
public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T min(Collection<? extends T> coll) {
    Iterator<? extends T> i = coll.iterator();
    T candidate = i.next();

    while (i.hasNext()) {
        T next = i.next();
        if (next.compareTo(candidate) < 0)
            candidate = next;
    }
    return candidate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It checks each word first letter ASCII code.
If the ASCII code of that first letter is small then others then it will consider as small string other wise it will consider it is larger then others.